# Java JFrame focus uppon opening needing a mouse click

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe, focus

Fist of all, I have been looking at this question on many forums and looked through a lot and haven't found my answer. Sorry if it is out there and missed it.

Now, I make a game with JFrame, I created a class window and am trying to get it focused uppon opening. You will see I made a WindowFocusListener, all of the following SysPrint gives true but the "isFocusOwner", even though it prints when called as an event of windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e), and the requestFocus returns true. Thus I am confused, here's the code:

```
public class Window extends Canvas {
    public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

        frame.setPreferredSize(LoadSaved());
        frame.setMaximumSize(LoadSaved());
        frame.setMinimumSize(LoadSaved());
        frame.setUndecorated(FullScrean());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.add(game);
        frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.toFront();
        frame.requestFocusInWindow();

        frame.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowFocusListener() {
            public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
                System.out.println(frame.isFocusOwner()); //prints false
                System.out.println(frame.isFocusable()); //prints true
                System.out.println(frame.isVisible()); //prints true
                System.out.println(frame.isActive()); //prints true
                System.out.println(frame.isAlwaysOnTop()); //prints true
                System.out.println(frame.isAutoRequestFocus()); //prints true
            }
        });     
        frame.setVisible(true);
        game.start();
    }
}
```

My only other idea would be my thread in "game.start()" interfering, as I am not too confident in my knowledge in this, here is a part of my main Game class that could help:

```
public class Game extends Canvas {
    public Game() {
        new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Magic Online", this);
    }

    //The thread
    public synchronized void start() {
        if (running)
            return;
        running = true;
        init();
        Thread threadVisual = new Thread() {

            //The game loop
            public void run() {
                long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
                double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
                double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
                double delta = 0;
                long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
                int updates = 0;
                int frames = 0;
                while (running) {
                    long now = System.nanoTime();
                    delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
                    lastTime = now;
                    while (delta >= 1) {
                        render();
                        updates++;
                        delta--;
                    }
                    frames++;
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                        timer += 1000;
                        System.out.println("FPS: " + frames + " TICKS: " + updates);
                        frames = 0;
                        updates = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        threadVisual.start();
    }

    public void init() {
        WIDTH = getWidth();
        HEIGHT = getHeight();
        tex = new Texture();

        mouse = new Mouse();
        sound = new Sound();
        key = new Keyboard();
        renderer = new Renderer();
        Shell.addShell(new Shell(new Main()));
        this.addKeyListener(key);
        this.addMouseListener(mouse);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(mouse);
        this.addMouseWheelListener(mouse);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Game();
    }
}
```

Sorry for the length, I tried to crop out most of unrelated code, I believe everything is here to find my answer. If you absolutely need a SSCCE, I'll make one, but rather not have to work around all my texture. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener`, it solves the focus related issues

Comment: Why are your classes extending Canvas? There is no need to do that.

Comment: You are partially right. My Window class does not need it, it came from a previous version and I missed it. Although, my Game class does need it, it contains all listeners and the BufferStrategy.

As for Key Bindings, I'll look into it, I tough it was for specific keys, like a "space" key doing X in general, where you don't was it to do so when X textArea is focused. This is not my case, unless I am missing something, could you elaborate please? Maybe my problem is related to where and when the KeyListener is called and added?